# How can I change the visibility of a secret Facebook Group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

My Facebook group has roughly a thousand members.

While I was on vacation, I let someone else admin in my place. Well, this person switched my group to secret, I need to change it back to Open.

I read that all the members had to agree to change it back. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to change that under "Group settings" while inside the group (see under the gear icon). In it, you can switch the privacy options of the group, so in this case you can switch it to Open group.